# Resolving XSD's using Ivy

Tags: ant, xsd, ivy

Forgive the double post but I am keen on an answer to this.

I would like some advice as to the approach I am taking. I am using Ivy for dependency management and am able to download and use all my jar files no issues. I would like to also run the `<schemavalidate>` task in Ant and would like to use Ivy to download the xsd's and dtd's as specified, thereby eliminating the need for a network connection after the initial download and also reducing my build time. I think I have a solution but wanted to run it
by some extra eyes for a sanity check and suggestions for possible improvements. Below is the relevant parts of my build scripts. The first call to retrieve uses my default ivysettings.xml and second call uses a settings file specific for retrieving xsd's and dtd's. Any feedback would be appreciated.

build.xml:

```
<project etc>
    ...

    <target name="resolve" description="Retrieve dependencies with ivy">
        <ivy:retrieve refresh="true"
                  sync="true"
                  conf="compile,war,runtime,test,findbugs"
                  pattern="${ivy.lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        <ivy:settings id="xsd.settings" 
                      file="${search.server.home}/ivysettings-xsd.xml"/>
        <ivy:retrieve settingsref="xsd.settings"
                  refresh="false"
                  sync="false"
                  conf="xmlentities"
                  pattern="${ivy.lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
    </target>
    ...
</project>
```

ivy.xml:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Jar files defined here but removed for brevity -->
        ...
        <dependency org="beans" name="spring-beans" rev="3.0" conf="xmlentities->default">
            <artifact name="spring-beans" type="xsd"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="context" name="spring-context" rev="3.0" conf="xmlentities->default">
            <artifact name="spring-context" type="xsd"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="mvc" name="spring-mvc" rev="3.0" conf="xmlentities->default">
            <artifact name="spring-mvc" type="xsd"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="tool" name="spring-tool" rev="3.0" conf="xmlentities->default">
            <artifact name="spring-tool" type="xsd"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="util" name="spring-util" rev="3.0" conf="xmlentities->default">
            <artifact name="spring-util" type="xsd"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="javaee" name="javaee" rev="5" conf="xmlentities->default">
            <artifact name="javaee_5" type="xsd"/>
            <artifact name="web-app_2_5" type="xsd"/>
            <artifact name="javaee_web_services_client_1_2" type="xsd"/>
            <artifact name="jsp_2_1" type="xsd"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="xmlschema" name="xmlschema" rev="2001" conf="xmlentities->default">
            <artifact name="XMLSchema" type="xsd"/>
            <artifact name="xml" type="xsd"/>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

ivysettings-xsd.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="namespaces"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="namespaces" returnFirst="true">
            <url name="w3-org-ns" checksums="">
                <artifact pattern="http://www.w3.org/2001/[artifact].[ext]"/>
            </url>
            <url name="javaee-ns" checksums="">
                <artifact pattern="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/[artifact].[ext]"/>
            </url>
            <url name="spring-ns" checksums="">
                <artifact pattern="http://www.springframework.org/schema/[organisation]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
            </url>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Ben

Comment: I don't understand why you are performing two retrieve actions and not just retrieving the XSDs and DTDs at the same time as the jars. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem. Caching the Schema files enables off-line validation.

As Tom stated I think only a single retrieve is needed. (My example fetches both jars and schema files)

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
```

I've offered some changes to the ivy and settings files.

### ivy.xml

I've used [ivy extra attributes](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html#extra) to assist with the generation of the Spring Schema URLs:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb.demo" module="spring"/>

    <configurations defaultconfmapping="compile->default">
        <conf name="compile" description="Compile dependencies"/>
        <conf name="schemas" description="XML schema files"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile depedencies -->
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="3.0.6.RELEASE"/>

        <!-- Schema dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="schemas" rev="3.0" conf="schemas->default">
            <artifact name="spring-beans"   e:framework="beans" type="xsd"/>
            <artifact name="spring-context" e:framework="context" type="xsd"/>
            <artifact name="spring-mvc"     e:framework="mvc"   type="xsd"/>
            <artifact name="spring-tool"    e:framework="tool"  type="xsd"/>
            <artifact name="spring-util"    e:framework="util"  type="xsd"/>
        </dependency>

        <dependency org="com.sun.java" name="schemas" rev="5" conf="schemas->default">
            <artifact name="javaee_5"    type="xsd"/>
            <artifact name="web-app_2_5" type="xsd"/>
            <artifact name="javaee_web_services_client_1_2" type="xsd"/>
            <artifact name="jsp_2_1"     type="xsd"/>
        </dependency>

        <dependency org="org.w3" name="schemas" rev="2001" conf="schemas->default">
            <artifact name="XMLSchema" type="xsd"/>
            <artifact name="xml"       type="xsd"/>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

### ivysettings.xml

Configure ivy to use Maven repositories by default. Use a [modules](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/modules.html) declaration to route the special schema modules to your URL resolvers.

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="maven-repos"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="maven-repos">
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
            ..
            Other Maven repositories go here
            ..
        </chain>
        <url name="spring-schemas">
            <artifact pattern="http://www.springframework.org/schema/[framework]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </url>
        <url name="javaee-schemas">
            <artifact pattern="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </url>
        <url name="w3-schemas">
            <artifact pattern="http://www.w3.org/2001/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </url>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module organisation="org.springframework" name="schemas" resolver="spring-schemas"/>
        <module organisation="com.sun.java" name="schemas" resolver="javaee-schemas"/>
        <module organisation="org.w3"       name="schemas" resolver="w3-schemas"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the advice. I like the look of extra attributes. That is a really elegant solution to the problem. It has been a while since I did this and posted, but if I remember correctly, I split the retrieval of the jars and xsd's to have a separation of concerns. In hindsight it is probably not the best idea.