# ivy cannot d/l file but wget can

Tags: ant, build, ivy

My ivy dependency:

> ```
> <dependency org="googlecode.com" name="jslint4java" rev="2.0.1" e:suffix="-src">
>   <artifact name="jslint4java" type="zip"/>
> </dependency>
> ```

My ivy settings:

> ```
> <url name="googlecode">
>   <artifact pattern="http://[module].[organization]/files/[artifact]-[revision][suffix].[ext]"/>
> </url>
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> <module organisation="googlecode.com" resolver="googlecode"/>
> ```

When I try to resolve the dependencies, I got the following error:

> [ivy:retrieve] == resolving dependencies
>
> ...#blog;working@...->googlecode.com#jslint4java;2.0.2
>
> [default->*] [ivy:retrieve]       tried
>
> http://jslint4java.googlecode.com/files/jslint4java-2.0.2-dist.zip
>
> [ivy:retrieve] **CLIENT ERROR: Not Found**
>
> url=http://jslint4java.googlecode.com/files/jslint4java-2.0.2-dist.zip
>
> [ivy:retrieve]    googlecode: no ivy file nor artifact found for
>
> googlecode.com#jslint4java;2.0.2 [ivy:retrieve] WARN:     module not found: googlecode.com#jslint4java;2.0.2 [ivy:retrieve] WARN: ====
>
> googlecode: tried [ivy:retrieve] WARN:   -- artifact
>
> googlecode.com#jslint4java;2.0.2!jslint4java.zip: [ivy:retrieve] WARN:
>
> **http://jslint4java.googlecode.com/files/jslint4java-2.0.2-dist.zip**

I tried to d/l the file by using the url in the last line with `wget` and the it went well.

But I cannot figure out why ivy failed to d/l the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ran the ant task with -d flag to check more info and that's the outcome:

```
[ivy:resolve] HTTP response status: 404 url=http://jslint4java.googlecode.com/files/jslint4java-2.0.1-src.zip.sha1
[ivy:resolve] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://jslint4java.googlecode.com/files/jslint4java-2.0.1-src.zip.sha1
[ivy:resolve] HTTP response status: 404 url=http://jslint4java.googlecode.com/files/jslint4java-2.0.1-src.zip.md5
[ivy:resolve] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://jslint4java.googlecode.com/files/jslint4java-2.0.1-src.zip.md5
```

Notice that md5 doesn't exist, you have to override the checksums option in the resolver.

```
<url name="googlecode" checksums="sha1">
```

I tried the sha1 ONLY, (the default is sha1,md5) and it worked, even though the sha1 failed to download as well.

try to experiment in that area.

Comment: hmmm...why i did not notice ivy is trying to d/l the digest. i will check again. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you setup a configuration in your ivy file.

## Example

After running the build the following files are present:

```
|-- build.xml
|-- ivysettings.xml
|-- ivy.xml
`-- lib
    `-- jslint4java-2.0.1-src.zip
```

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="source"  description="source code distro"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="googlecode.com" name="jslint4java" rev="2.0.1" e:suffix="src" conf="source->default">
            <artifact name="jslint4java" type="zip"/>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Notes:

- Added a "source" configuration. Logical grouping within my ivy project to differentiate from other kinds of dependency.
- Note the extra "conf" attribute on the dependency. Mapped to the remote "default" configuration. Unless the remote module has an ivy or POM file default is the safest option.
- Revised the extra attribute "suffix". Removed the "-" character. Not a big deal technically, I just think it's best not included in the dependency declaration.

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="googlecode" />
  <resolvers>
    <url name="googlecode">
      <artifact pattern="http://[module].[organization]/files/[artifact]-[revision]-[suffix].[ext]"/>
    </url>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Notes:

- Personally I would explicitly state the hostname of the remote repository, here in the settings file ([Instead of taking it from the dependency information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249926/how-to-use-the-ext-variable-in-ivy/12253549#12253549)). This will work though.

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="retrieve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="retrieve" description="Use ivy to retrieve artifacts">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[suffix]).[ext]" conf="source"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleanup build files">
        <delete dir="lib"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- Note how the "suffix" attribute is enclosed within parenthesis. This is an optional extra parameter and may not be part of a dependency.